# extract lines fitting a character pattern followed by variable numbers

Tags: awk

I have a file with several columns and I would like to extract only those lines which have in the 8th column a value higher than 0.7 (maximum will be 1). My 8th column looks like this:

```
DR2=0.05;AF=0.0009;IMP
DR2=0.05;AF=0.0017;IMP
DR2=0.74;AF=0.0012;IMP
```

I've tried the following code in awk:

```
 awk '{$8 ~ /^DR2=[>0.7]*/ }' myfile > myfile.filtered
```

I've tried only recognising the "DR2=" part and it works, so the problem seems to be the numbers part.

Thank you very much in advanced, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk  '$8 ~ /^DR2=/ { if (substr($8,5) > 0.7) print }' myfile > myfile.filtered
```

Comment: @SoniaOlaecheaLázaro, small mistake, check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks @RomeoNinov, I've also updated my question with a mistake (I want to filter by the 8th column, not the 4th)... could you please change again your code based on my update, please? Sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should post compleet samples, based on your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '$8 ~ /^DR2=/{split($8,array,"[=;]");if(array[2]>0.7){print}}' Input_file
```

Comment: @SoniaOlaecheaLázaro, could you please try above once?

Comment: Seems like you are shooting at a moving target.... (I really meant 8th field not 4th...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, OP mentioned it first 4th field and now changed it to 8th field :) I too changed my solution now.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the troubles, I'm just beginning with programming! Both your solutions wotk with my problem so thank you very much!

Comment: @SoniaOlaecheaLázaro, glad that it helped you, give it sometime and you can select any of the answer as correct answer :)

Comment: I'm so sorry, but as I don't have a reputation of more than 15 my vote won't count...

Comment: @SoniaOlaecheaLázaro, that is up-vote this is selecting an answer as right which anyone could do, look for a check option :)

Comment: @SoniaOlaecheaLázaro, can't see it :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
awk 'gensub("^.*DR2=([0-9\.]+).*$", "\\1", 1, $4) > 0.7' myfile
```